# Any way to control the scaling of Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, scale

I'm trying to have my Swing components not scale either vertically and scale horizontally, or the other way around (In other words, I only want them to have one axis of freedom. They can either scale horizontally in some cases, or vertically in others).

Is there any elegant way of doing this, without adding a multitude of JPanels?

LE: I'd rather not make any significant modifications to the already made layout that I've received.

I'm hoping for a magical, simple fix to this issue, like JTextField.don'tScaleVerticallyIdiot();

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an appropriate layout manager.

The two most powerful are [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) and [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). I personally prefer MigLayout because it's easier to use directly, whereas FormLayout works well only with a window designer like [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Both have similar feature characteristics.

Using MigLayout, you can specify if a component is allowed to grow on a specific axis, and if so, what kind of weight it should be provided (as opposed to extra space going to other components).

Comment: I'd rather avoid any large changes to the complete and complex layout I've received...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that with setting [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) as a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager2.html) of the container, so:

- Adding swing component on **[BorderLayout.EAST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#EAST)** will make it scalable *vertically* only.
- Adding swing component on **[BorderLayout.WEST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#WEST)** will make it scalable *vertically* only.
- Adding swing component on **[BorderLayout.NORTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#NORTH)** will make it scalable *horizontally* only.
- Adding swing component on **[BorderLayout.SOUTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#SOUTH)** will make it scalable *horizontally* only.
- Adding swing component on **[BorderLayout.CENTER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER)** will make it scalable both *horizontally* and *vertically*.

Comment: I would've loved it to work as easily as that, however it still scales according to the JFrame. I want it to be a single row as height and scale horizontally as much as I drag the frame, but without adding multiple JPanels.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which `LayoutManager` that you are currently using.

Personally, I would use `GridBagLayout` for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems as if the old sun forums have become a ghost town since they merged with the oracle forums.

Comment: `1)` something went wrong after migrations of posts from `forums.sun.com` to `ghost town` :-), `2)` and `ghost town` has one big issue, you can't searching in posts history, google returns nothing, 3) most of answerers were active on two or more Java Forums

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to be a single row as height and scale horizontally as much as I drag the frame, but without adding multiple JPanels.

I think `BoxLayout` with a `PAGE_AXIS` can do that.